# Node.js Sequelize: multiple condition on 'where'

Tags: sql, reactjs, axios, sequelize.js

How do i query a table with multiple conditions? This give me no error but, only run the first condition!

```
exports.findAllLimit = (req, res) => {

 const titulo  = req.query.titulo ;
 var condition = titulo ? { titulo : { [Op.iLike]: `%${titulo }%` } } : null;
 var condition2 = {stock: {  [Op.ne]: 0}};

 Produtos.findAll({ 
 where:  condition , condition2,
 include: [Categorias], 
  order: [ 
   ['id', 'ASC']
         ],
  limit: 9
  })
.then(data => {
  res.send(data);
})
.catch(err => {
  res.status(500).send({
    message:
        err.message || "Ocorreu um erro a retirar os dados do backend!."
  });
   });
 };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create here an object with property condition2 and it's value.
You need to merge these 2 conditions, and assign them on where.
so you can use:

```
where: Object.assign({}, condition , condition2),
```

OR:

```
where: {...condition, ...condition2}
```

Comment: "where: Object.assign({}, condition , condition2)", Works! =) ty

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this for multiple condition .

```
const titulo  = req.query.titulo ;
var condition = titulo
  ? {
      titulo: {
        [Op.iLike]: `%${titulo}%`,
      },
    }
  : null;
var condition2 = {
  stock: {
    [Op.ne]: 0,
  },
};

let where = [];
where.push(condition);
where.push(condition2);

Produtos.findAll({
  where,
});
```